# Associate model classes Django with instances of another model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-contenttypes, generic-relations

*Heavily edited in response to comment by @Todor.*

[I use Django 1.7.6 and Python 3.4.1.]

—

So in my Django project I've defined an `Item` model with various specific subclassing models. I've also defined a `Category` model. A toy version of my models looks like:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class CleeseItem(Item):
    cleese = models.URLField()

class GilliamItem(Item):
    gilliam = models.IntegerField()

class JonesItem(Item):
    jones = models.EmailField()

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    item_types = ????  # List of model classes
```

Now, the `????` above is my question. To each `Category` instance, I'd like to associate a list of `Item` subclasses. Not individual `Item` instances, but `Item` *subclasses*.

*Example: Say I create a particular `Category` instance `<Category: terry>`. Now I want to tell Django that the `GilliamItem` and `JonesItem` subclasses belong to the "terry" `Category`.*

—

How will I use this? I'd like to write a view as follows:

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from monty.models import Category

def category_page(request, cat_name):
    c = get_object_or_404(Category, name=cat_name)
    item_dict = {}
    for it in c.item_types:  # Recall item_types is a list of classes
        item_dict.update( {it.verbose_name_plural: it.objects.all()} )
    return render_to_response('category_page.html', {'items': item_dict})
```

Namely, my view (1) retrieves a `Category` object; (2) constructs a dictionary in which the keys are the names of the models associated with that `Category` and the values are QuerySets containing all instances of those models; and (3) supplies that dictionary to the template.

*Example: I visit `http://domain.com/category/terry/`. The view retrieves the `Category` object with `name='terry'` from the database. `c.item_types` in line 7 produces `[GilliamItem, JonesItem]`, so the dictionary winds up looking like `{ 'gilliam items': GilliamItem.objects.all(), 'jones items': JonesItem.objects.all() }`*.

—

Finally, I'd like a site administrator to be able to rearrange arbitrarily the mapping between `Category` objects and `Item` types through the admin site. *(Example: One day I might decide to edit the "Terry" `Category` to remove `JonesItem` from `item_types`, and perhaps add `PratchettItem`.)*

Comment: How do you plan to "add subclasses" to a category instance? From the admin? And more important how/where do you plan to store that information? And finally, how do you plan to use this? If `c =  <Category: Terry>`, what do you want to be able to do with `c`? E.g. you want `c.items.all()` to return a `queryset` of items only from `GilliamItem` and `JonesItem`? Or you need/want something more? If so what is it?

Comment: @Todor Thank you for this question — in attempting to answer it I clarified the problem a lot in my own head. I updated the question significantly to address your questions, but in short: Yes, I'd like to assign subclasses to category instances via the admin. And no, I don't want one big polymorphic QuerySet but a dict containing the appropriate individual QuerySets.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [django-polymorphic](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).  It provides foreign-key and many-to-many relationships for inherited models.

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected, I'm making headway using the [`ContentTypes` framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType). In particular, if I edit my `Category` model to look like

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    item_types = models.ManyToManyField(ContentType, null=True, blank=True)
```

I get almost exactly what I want. The only remaining problem is that this evokes *all* the model classes in my project, whereas I am interested only in the subclasses of `Item`. But I'm getting close!

Comment: Use the [`formfield_for_manytomany`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_manytomany) hook in the admin to filter the queryset. I guess the query set can look like that: `ContentType.objects.filter(model__endswith='Item')`